# How do I prevent service block from starting

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm new to Anylogic, and I was wondering if it's possible to hold delay process when the shift is over eve if the process already started.

I'm trying to write some code in the service action but i don't find the correct code lines.

i expect the flow process should stop until the next resource shift will start.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi @Nave, Please share the more details and code on which you are trying with the specific issue.

Comment: my process include one service block that require one resource.
the availability of the resource is define by shifts schedule.

Comment: my process include one service block that require one resource.
the availability of the resource is define by shifts schedule.
i want to make sure that  process that was starting in  the service block that require resource, before the shift end time (when the resource was available)
will stop or even wont start in head if the time until the end of the shift is smaller the delay time of the service

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the custom resource choice in the service block:

[image: resource choice]

```
self.delayTime(agent)<schedule.getTimeoutToNextValue()
```

This means that a resource can only be chosen if the delay time for that agent will be smaller that the time for the next schedule event.

If you have doubts on how time units are working on your model, you can play safe and explicitly define the time units like this if the delay time is in hours.

```
self.delayTime(agent, HOUR)<schedule.getTimeoutToNextValue()
```

Be sure that your model time is in hours, because the function getTimeoutToNextValue will be defined depending on the time units you are using in your model.

Comment: ok, but now when the next shift start, that agent stay in the queue and does't progress to the delay process.
what do i need to define so in the next shift the agent will progress?

Comment: false.. when the shift starts... it will progress... try it out

Comment: if in your model it doesn't progress, then you are doing something wrong and I don't have information on your model to know what is wrong...

Comment: my model is very simple. it include only one service block with delay time for 2 hours. the resource availability is define by schedule of shifts (every day between 8 am to 5 pm). if i run my model , start at 4 pm , i expect that the agent wont progress until 8 am in the day after, but in fact it wont progress even in the day after.

Comment: I tested this on my own and it works... check my model here: https://ufile.io/56oepqkd and try to find out what are the differences and maybe you can find your error

Comment: i think ifid the source of the problem, but still, i don't know what i should fix.
in your model you use schdule with duration type is: Custom (no calendar mapping) and i use week type, this is the only diffrent i found, there is  a way to attach here the model?

Comment: maybe you have a mess with your model time units... this should work with any kind of schedule

Comment: and you can upload the model the same way i did it

Comment: check my edit... make that correction, and you are ready to go

Comment: still not working, the model is running, but the agents stuck in the queue, and not progress to delay step.

Comment: then i don't know... i did that on the model you sent me and it works so you have probably a lot of other errors so i guess we are done here... if you want additional help you will have to ask a question with a lot more details... good luck