# How do I match the availability of the resource in the edge of the shift

Tags: anylogic

i am defining a shift schedule so the process should stop when the resource isn't available according the schedule or when the time until the end of the shift is shorter then the delay time of the relevant process.

i already try the code line: self.delaytime(agent)

self.delaytime(agent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent service block from starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883613/how-do-i-prevent-service-block-from-starting)

Comment: This question makes sense to me, but it is a duplicate of 56883613.

Comment: ok,please tell me what should i do to get your help for this issue?